# Google BigQuery: "Unexpected" error while limiting rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery and I'm getting a vague error when I try to limit the number of rows returned by my query.

Here is a query that seems to be valid (though the number of results returned is too high):

```
SELECT 1 AS Number_of_Records,
  [country] AS country,
  [day] AS day,
  [max_gust_wind_speed] AS max_gust_wind_speed,
  [max_sustained_wind_speed] AS max_sustained_wind_speed,
  [max_temperature] AS max_temperature,
  [max_temperature_explicit] AS max_temperature_explicit,
  [year] AS year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed] gsod_update_fixed
```

But this one gives me a "Unexpected. Please try again." error message:

```
SELECT 1 AS Number_of_Records,
  [country] AS country,
  [day] AS day,
  [max_gust_wind_speed] AS max_gust_wind_speed,
  [max_sustained_wind_speed] AS max_sustained_wind_speed,
  [max_temperature] AS max_temperature,
  [max_temperature_explicit] AS max_temperature_explicit,
  [year] AS year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed] gsod_update_fixed
LIMIT 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: This original query now works, so why does this one fail?

```
SELECT 1 AS Number_of_Records,
  [alt] AS alt,
  [col] AS col,
  [country] AS country,
  [day] AS day,
  [fog] AS fog,
  [hail] AS hail,
  [lat] AS lat,
  [long] AS long,
  [max_gust_wind_speed] AS max_gust_wind_speed,
  [max_sustained_wind_speed] AS max_sustained_wind_speed,
  [max_temperature] AS max_temperature,
  [max_temperature_explicit] AS max_temperature_explicit,
  [mean_dew_point] AS mean_dew_point,
  [mean_sealevel_pressure] AS mean_sealevel_pressure,
  [mean_station_pressure] AS mean_station_pressure,
  [mean_temp] AS mean_temp,
  [mean_visibility] AS mean_visibility,
  [mean_wind_speed] AS mean_wind_speed,
  [min_temperature] AS min_temperature,
  [min_temperature_explicit] AS min_temperature_explicit,
  [month] AS month,
  [num_mean_dew_point_samples] AS num_mean_dew_point_samples,
  [num_mean_sealevel_pressure_samples] AS num_mean_sealevel_pressure_samples,
  [num_mean_station_pressure_samples] AS num_mean_station_pressure_samples,
  [num_mean_temp_samples] AS num_mean_temp_samples,
  [num_mean_visibility_samples] AS num_mean_visibility_samples,
  [num_mean_wind_speed_samples] AS num_mean_wind_speed_samples,
  [rain] AS rain,
  [snow] AS snow,
  [snow_depth] AS snow_depth,
  [state] AS state,
  [station_number] AS station_number,
  [thunder] AS thunder,
  [tornado] AS tornado,
  [total_precipitation] AS total_precipitation,
  [wban_number] AS wban_number,
  [year] AS year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed] gsod_update_fixed
LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for the query:

```
SELECT 
  [country] AS country,
  [day] AS day,
  [max_gust_wind_speed] AS max_gust_wind_speed,
  [max_sustained_wind_speed] AS max_sustained_wind_speed,
  [max_temperature] AS max_temperature,
  [max_temperature_explicit] AS max_temperature_explicit,
  [year] AS year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed] gsod_update_fixed
LIMIT 12
```

(Removing the `1 AS Number_of_Records` constant column works - though this shouldn't be a problem in theory)

Comment: Note that Fh. filed a bug and we're investigating why the constant column causes queries to fail.

Comment: @JordanTigani Has there been any progress on this?

Comment: Yes, this should be fixed.

Comment: Fh, I added a similar query to my post that still does not work and I am wondering if this is the same bug or if I am doing something wrong -- any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: An alternative workaround in the meantime: Move the LIMIT to an outer query. Instead of 
"SELECT 1 AS x, year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed] LIMIT 1", do "SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 1 AS x, year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed]
) LIMIT 1"

Comment: Would you mind enlightening me as to what the problem was? I am trying to isolate if this is a problem specific to this data source, or if there is a general issue on my end with the way I am querying with BQ. I haven't been able to repro this with tables that are not from bigquery-samples, so I'd like to know if it is the former. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that should be fixed as of this morning. Please let us know if you continue to see the problem.

Comment: I just tried running the same query again via the web interface and it's still failing for me.

Comment: Hi Jordan, just checking in again, this query still fails, is this being addressed?

Comment: Looks like the problem still exists in the latest query engine (Dremel) release. Sorry about that, we're looking into it.

Comment: Okay, cool, the original query works now. However I tried a longer one that selects more columns and it fails with the same "unexpected" error. I added the longer query to my original post. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like the same situation as before -- when I remove "1 AS Number_of_Records" it works fine.

Comment: An alternative workaround in the meantime: Move the LIMIT to an outer query. Instead of 
"SELECT 1 AS x, year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed] LIMIT 1", do "SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 1 AS x, year
FROM [bigquery-samples:weather_geo.gsod_update_fixed]
) LIMIT 1"