# Multiple Unexpected Results in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a pretty huge query that join multiple tables (fact table with its dimension tables) in a destination table.

The fact table is about **40M rows**.

it is of the following form:

```
SELECT
 ...
FROM (
  SELECT
   ...
  FROM (
    ...
  ) AS base
  LEFT JOIN  dim_table_1 ON dim_table_1.field1 = base.field1
) AS base2
LEFT JOIN dim_table_2 ON dim_table_2.field2 = base2.field2
```

I ran the query **two times** and it failed each time after several hours of computation
Here is the log in the BigQuery UI:

```
Errors:
Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: job_bVDu4XlJSpWCIeLTfrWpOHVN5nU
Start Time: 2:38pm, 4 Dec 2013
End Time: 8:38pm, 4 Dec 2013
Destination Table: <destination_table>
Write Preference: Overwrite table
Allow Large Results: true
Priority: Batch
```

EDIT:
Any tips on how I can optimize the query or what workflow changes to do so it will work ?

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll look at this more a bit later (you've got a lot going on in your query -- 8 joins -- so it may take a little bit of digging to find the problem).

The latest query engine release has a regression when selecting a constant field (see [Google BigQuery: "Unexpected" error while limiting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361012/google-bigquery-unexpected-error-while-limiting-rows)), that you might be hitting (i.e. the "MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()/1000)" in your query may be hitting this problem). We should be releasing a fix for this today.

The other possibility is that you have a join explosion -- i.e. you're joining on non-unique keys and end up with more rows than you started out with.

As I mentioned, I'll investigate further when I get more time and I'll update this answer when I do.

Comment: I am almost sure that there is no join explosion but I will check. Thanks for the update. If i put static value like `123456789` for the timestamp field instead of MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()/1000), could it solve the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, a static constant won't affect the issue.

Comment: I have removed the constant value and it worked. Thanks for the tip